# Notification Not showing android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm having a little issue with a notification that I want it to show in 24 hours before a specific time, which will be selected by the user, but my notification isn't showing for some reason

**Here's how i'm setting the notification:**

```
private void alarm(String pseudo, Date date){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("pseudo",pseudo);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm before 24hours before the selected date
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        intent.putExtra("DateVaccin",calendar.getTime());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Prochaine Notification le "+ calendar.getTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getSharedPreferences(pseudo, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putLong("DateVacc", calendar.getTimeInMillis()).commit();
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),alarmIntent);
    }
```

**and here's my alarmReceiver class:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification déclanchée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.button_bb_selec)
                        .setContentTitle("Notification Vaccin")
                        .setContentText(intent.getExtras().getString("DateVaccin"));

        //TODO : get to another activity!!

       NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int mNotificationId = 1;

        mNotificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `BroadcastReceiver` class should be in its own separate file – or it has to be `public static`, if you really want to keep it where you have it now – and have a `<receiver>` entry in the manifest.

Comment: in it's own file? how's that? the receiver in the manifest is already set in the manifest file

Comment: I'd edited my comment. What's the `<receiver>` entry look like?

Comment: `<receiver android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEstLa.CarnetSante.VaccinActivity.AlarmReceiver"/>` that's my receiver in the manifest and the class AlarmReceiver is public static

Comment: The `name` is a little different for nested classes - `android:name=".Activities.Menu.BBEstLa.CarnetSante.VaccinAct‌​ivity$AlarmReceiver"`‌. Notice the `$`.

Comment: there's no `$` sign showing in my receiver !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152107/discussion-between-mohammed-amin-aimeur-and-mike-m).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. That's how you have to specify the `name` in the `<receiver>` element. The `$` isn't actually in the class name.

Comment: Oh! so you want me to declare my receiver using the $ sign !! does that work? I never tried it before

Comment: Yeah, it works, if you've got it setup correctly. The class must be `public static`, and you have to get the `name` right.

Comment: for some reason now the notification is showing no matter what day I choose !!!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the `Date`.

Comment: Can you help me locate that? it's killing me to fix it

Comment: There's nothing in your post that shows how you're setting the `Date`. Do some debugging to check the time when it's passed to `alarm()`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot man, I guess the first problem was with the receiver, I might miss-typed something overthere!

Comment: @MikeM. Now it works but the notification shows on then off in seconds!! this is driving me insane!!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. If you mean it gets dismissed, then the only things I can think of are that you're dismissing it somewhere in your code too early, or maybe your device has some mechanism that cleans up notifications, or similar.

Comment: yeah I guess the device is dismissing it, I got one last question please, when my app is closed the notification doesn't appear! can you help me with that? @MikeM.

Comment: That sounds like a device-specific thing again. With standard Android, if you've got the Receiver registered in the manifest, and the notification works to begin with, then it'll work even if your app is not running. All I can suggest is to check the device Settings to see if there's anything related there, or possibly some separate security or device management app that might be interfering. I don't have any experience with such devices, so I can't really give any specifics.

Comment: just in case you know something about it, it's an oppo neo7 using android 5.1

Comment: Yeah, no clue. Sorry. I would not be surprised, though, if that is indeed the cause of both problems. Chinese manufacturers are notorious for messing with Android like that.